# Mixing Visual Studio solution with CMake projects

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I have a Visual Studio 2022 solution, with a main project `main` which uses a CMake library `foo` internaly as a reference project.
The CMake library has headers, and I want the `main` project to get the inlculde folder from the `foo` project **without** having to add it to the `main` project "Additional Include Directories".

[here](https://github.com/yoavmil/MSVC_CMAKE_INTEGRATION) is a minimal example.

I think I am looking for a cmake command that informs VS where the headers area, or I am using cmake wrong whatsoever. PEASE ADVICE.

some snippets for clarifying.

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include "foo.h" /// <-- don't know foo.h !
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << lib_name() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

library CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(CMakeLib)

add_library(foo STATIC
    foo.cpp
    foo.h
)

target_include_directories(foo
    PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)
```

Library header and source file:

```cpp
const char* lib_name();
#include "foo.h"

const char* lib_name()
{
    return "foo";
}
```